# (IPA) International Phonetic Alphabet the character shows okay in mac but not in windows

Tags: java, javafx

I am working with an application that display IPA Characters from a Json File.
I am using an IMac with Netbeans and the application works good but if I compile
the project and execute it in a windows computer it shows a different character
not even an IPA character.
I already tried changing different Fonts family and the result is the same.

```java
public class JavaFXApplicationJsonFile extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Print JsonFile");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                String jsonFileString = "src/javafxapplicationjsonfile/jsonFile.json";


                try {
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFileString);

                    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(fileReader);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("palabras");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Palabras = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        System.out.println(Palabras.get("IPA").toString());

                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, Palabras.get("IPA").toString(), ButtonType.OK);
                        alert.show();
                    }



                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplicationJsonFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplicationJsonFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplicationJsonFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });



        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The Windows machine may simply not have any font installed that has the IPA characters. Please edit the question and show screen grabs of what you see in iMac and in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The FileReader class will use the operating system's default character set.

See InputStreamReader, particularly the constructors that take a CharSet or a Character Set Name.

You'll probably want to use UTF-8 (the default character set on Mac OS), since you say it works properly on Mac OS.

When you run it on Windows, the default character set is Windows-1252

Comment: From j11 `FileReader` has ctors that take a `Charset`. OTOH from j9 using JFX is less convenient :-(

Comment: Yes, but InputStreamReader has the ctors back to at least Java 7